# web cam does not work ubuntu 21.04 with Lenovo X1 Gen 9

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, webcam, 21.04

I can not get the integrated web cam working on my Lenovo X1 Gen 9 with Ubuntu 21.04. When opening Cheese I only see a black screen. It works with an external USB web cam. I have installed the latest updates and the latetes BIOS (1.39). The web cam shutter is open (no red dot).

Does anybody else has this problem and knows a solution? Any help is very appreciated.

Best
Nielson

Answer (score 1):

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
device="/dev/whatever"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, but there is one more step.

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.

Comment: Hi waltinator,

Thanks a lot for your support. I really appreciate that.

Comment: @nielson:Please click the checkmark to "accept" my answer, if it helped you.

Comment: I applied your permission changes (incl. reboot). Unfortunately it did not resolve the problem. Might it be the case that Ubuntu 2021.04 does not support the Lenovo X1 Gen 9? Do you have any other ideas I could check? Thanks again for your time and support. I really appreciate that.